# PHP DOM : getElementsbyTagName

Tags: php, dom

I fear that this is a really stupid question but I am really stuck after trying a load of combinations for the last 2 hours. I am trying to pull the NAME out of the XML file

My XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<userdata>
<name>John</name>
</userdata>
```

My php:

```
  $doc          =  new DOMDocument();
  $doc          -> load( "thefile.xml" );
  $thename       =  $doc -> getElementsByTagName( "name" );
$myname= $thename -> getElementsByTagName("name") -> item(0) -> nodeValue;
```

The Error:

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class DOMElement could not be converted to string in phpreader.php
```

I have tried

```
$myname= $thename -> getElementsByTagName("name") -> item(0) ;
$myname= $doc     -> getElementsByTagName("name") -> item(0) -> nodeValue;
$myname= $doc     -> getElementsByTagName("name") -> item(0) ;
```

but all fail. Guess I have tried just about every combination except the correct one :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may want `$myname = $thename->item(0)->nodeValue`. $thename is already the NodeList of all of the nodes whose tag is "name" - you want the first item of these (`->item(0)`), and you want the value of the node (`->nodeValue`). `$thename` should be more appropriately named `$names`, and you'd see why `$names->item(0)->nodeValue` makes sense semantically.

This Works For Me<sup>TM</sup>.

Comment: ok thanks Federico. Thanks for the clear explanation of this and the fix. I have been using the PHP DOM on and off for the last 5 months and I find it very difficult to remember. I am only using it very few weeks so I tend to forget the semantics :( And I have to stick with it... as someone else said I shoudl use the simpleXML. I am using that elsewhere and it is much easier!! But I am stuck with the old legacy PHP DOM in some parts. Thanks again!! :)

Answer (score 3):

This code run:

```
<?php
$xml = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<userdata>
    <name>John</name>
</userdata>
XML;

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($xml);
$names = $doc->firstChild->getElementsByTagName("name");
$myname = $names->item(0)->nodeValue;

var_dump($myname);
```

Comment: Hi Dylan. That code worked for me also in addition to Federicos .... however I accepted his answer on the basis that he answered first. However I am keeping your code as a workign 'toy' example for future reference - it is very useful!! Thanks :)