# Retrieve specific tag value out of multiple options from XML in PHP

Tags: php, xml

```
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();
    $path_to_dir = '/var/www/html/imgdone/'.$character.'/Annotation/'.$var_new.'';
    $xmlDoc->load($path_to_dir);
    $elements = $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('surface');
    $elements1 = $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('text');
    foreach($elements1 as $node)
    {
        foreach($node->childNodes as $child) 
        {
           if($child->nodeName=='p')
           {
            $path=$child->getAttribute();
            echo $path;
        //   $path_new=str_replace("\\", "/", $path);
        //   echo "<br>";
        //   $path_new1 = str_replace("Z:/home/ashutosh/Desktop/", "", $path_new);
        //   echo "<br>";
        //   echo '<img src="'.$path_new1.'"  height="150" width="200" />';

           }
        }
    }
```

I have a XML File and I am loading the XML file in PHP. I want to retrieve the `<p>` tag value from the XML value. However, there are 2 `<p>` tag names as you can see in the XML code below. I want to get the value of "p" tagname containing the "Cartoon Sketch_Non FrontalFace_Thoughtful_Young_Male_No Beard_No Glass" value.

How do I get that value onto a variable.

I am trying but not getting any value. I am new to PHP.
PHP code is posted above.

```
<TEI version="5.0" xml:id="_0001">
<teiHeader>
<fileDesc>
<titleStmt>
<title/>
</titleStmt>
<publicationStmt>
<p/>
</publicationStmt>
<sourceDesc>
**<p>194 x 260</p>**
</sourceDesc>
</fileDesc>
<label>
Image Markup Tool
</label>
<ref type="appURI" target="http://hcmc.uvic.ca/~mholmes/image_markup/">
</ref>
</teiHeader>
</surface>
</facsimile>
<text>
<body>
<div xml:id="imtImageAnnotations">
<div corresp="#imtArea_0" type="imtAnnotation"> 
<head>
Attributes
</head>
<div>
    **<p>Cartoon Sketch_Non Frontal Face_Thoughtful_Young_Male_No Beard_No Glass**
</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</text>
</TEI>
```

Comment: have you written any code --> edit your question, show it.

Comment: Edited, how is it to be done ?

Comment: the XML is not valid, e.g. closing tag without opening tag `<surfaces>` and `<facsimile>`. Look into `DOMXpath` to get to `/TEI/text/body/div/div/div/p`

Comment: Can't it be done using DOM element......please suggest

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6983738/php-dom-getelementsbytagname, http://php.net/manual/de/class.domdocument.php

Comment: `foreach($node->childNodes as $child)` child of `<text>` is `<body>`. This loop can't find the `<p>` node, because it is many levels deeper in the structure, see my above comment. Improve your code, if new questions arise, edit your question.

Comment: Guys, please help me, I am not able to find any answer to this question.

Comment: I can't see any effort on your part reflected by your question, even after several hints. SO is not a code-writing service.

Comment: I tried using XPath also but nothing comes and server error is obtained. I know SO is not that but some other hint or solution if you can give will be very helpful

Comment: Are you even reading the comments? First, the XML is not well-formed, so any XML parser will choke on it. Make sure the XML is correct before continuing. Secondly, have you tried to implement michi's solution? And did you take a look at the links provided?