# Get value from <p> tag from XML in PHP

Tags: php, xml

I have a XML and I want to retrieve the value inside `<p>` tag in PHP. How do I do that? I am trying `getElementbyId`, `getAttribute` but I am unable to get the data.

```
$xmlDoc = new DOMDocument();$path_to_dir = "/var/www/html/Dalai/Annotation/0001.xml";
$xmlDoc->load($path_to_dir);$elements1 = $xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('text');
foreach($elements1 as $node)
{
    foreach($node->childNodes as $child) 
    {
       if($child->nodeName=='p')
       {
        $path=$child->getAttribute();
        echo $path;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: seems OP posted his question again, this time without XML: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35253997/2016456. Please do not repost questions.

Answer (score 0):

I think in this line `$path=$child->getAttribute();` [getAttribute](http://php.net/manual/en/domelement.getattribute.php) should take a string as a parameter, which then returns a string.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that, by *the value inside `<p>`*, you mean the text content like `foo` in `<p>foo</p>`, then you can access it via *[`textContent`](http://at.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.textcontent) or [`nodeValue`](http://at.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.nodevalue)* * :

```
$path = $child->textContent;
//or $path = $child->nodeValue;
echo $path;
```

*) either one will do since it will be called on a `DOMElement` in this case. For more subtle differences between `textContent` and `nodeValue`, see : [PHP DOM textContent vs nodeValue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12380919/php-dom-textcontent-vs-nodevalue)